# Best way to implement mutliple Default Buttons on a ASP.NET Webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

What is the best way to implement mutliple Default Buttons on a ASP.NET Webform?

I have what I think is a pretty standard page. There is a login area with user/pass field and a login button. Then elsewhere on the same page there is a single search field with a search button.

Comment: Pedantry: *multiple

Please proofread your posts. At the very least, your subjects.

Comment: It's clear you are smarter than me but I still want to learn whatever lesson you are trying to teach me. Please edit my original question or subject to read as you believe is correct. Or make another comment. I appreciate the critique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`asp:Panel` has a property named `DefaultButton`. You just need to encapsulate your markup portions with appropriate panels and set the default buttons for each.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the enter key press for each area of the screen and then fire the corresponding button's click even.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper function like [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202073205/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/jawad/archive/2005/05/15/TextBoxButtonTie.aspx) to tie the textboxes to their associated buttons.